# Qt QML ComboBox override wheel events

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, qt5.5

Is there any way to override ComboBox MouseArea to ignore wheel event instead of changing current index? ComboBox itself has no option to change wheel focus behaviour. So far I've tried to override onWheel from CB MouseArea with code like this:

```
ComboBox {
  Component.onCompleted: {
    for (var i = 0; i < combobox_ctrl.children.length; ++i) {
      console.log(combobox_ctrl.children[i])
      console.log(combobox_ctrl.children[i].hasOwnProperty('onWheel'))

      if (combobox_ctrl.children[i].hasOwnProperty('onWheel')) {
        console.log(combobox_ctrl.children[i]['onWheel'])
        combobox_ctrl.children[i]['onWheel'] = function() { console.log("CB on wheel!") }
        //combobox_ctrl.children[i]onWheel = function() { console.log("CB on wheel!") 
        //combobox_ctrl.children[i].destroy()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I get

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read-only property "wheel"

Did anyone was able to disable wheel events on ComboBox in Qml?

// EDIT

for example in Slider control I was able to remove wheel event handling like this:

```
Slider {
  Component.onCompleted: {
    for (var i = 0; i < slider.children.length; ++i) {
      console.log(slider.children[i])
      if (slider.children[i].hasOwnProperty("onVerticalWheelMoved") && slider.children[i].hasOwnProperty("onHorizontalWheelMoved")) {
        console.log("Found wheel area!")
        slider.children[i].destroy()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But in slider WheelArea is not responsible for handling "click" events.

Answer (score 4):

You can place `MouseArea` over `ComboBox` and steal the wheel event.

```
ComboBox {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    model: [ "Banana", "Apple", "Coconut" ]
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onWheel: {
            // do nothing
        }
        onPressed: {
            // propogate to ComboBox
            mouse.accepted = false;
        }
        onReleased: {
            // propogate to ComboBox
            mouse.accepted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it will handle the event, so for example ScrollArea where combobox resides does not get the event also

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently possible, as `ComboBox` is not derived from `MouseArea`, but `FocusScope`, which has no support for these kinds of events.

A similar problem was mentioned in a suggestion recently:

[Disable mouse wheel scroll event on QtQuick.Controls](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48620)

---

If you're after a hacky way of doing it, it seems like the only option you have left is to apply a patch to `ComboBox.qml` that removes the `onWheel` handler:

```
diff --git a/src/controls/ComboBox.qml b/src/controls/ComboBox.qml
index 4e29dfe..3413cac 100644
--- a/src/controls/ComboBox.qml
+++ b/src/controls/ComboBox.qml
@@ -407,13 +407,6 @@ Control {
                 popup.toggleShow()
             overridePressed = false
         }
-        onWheel: {
-            if (wheel.angleDelta.y > 0) {
-                __selectPrevItem();
-            } else if (wheel.angleDelta.y < 0){
-                __selectNextItem();
-            }
-        }
     }
```

Another alternative that doesn't involve modifying Qt code would be to add an intermediate `MouseArea` *above* `ComboBox`'s, and then somehow only forward specific events through to `ComboBox`'s `MouseArea`. Or, create a custom C++ item that does the equivalent. You may have more control that way.

Comment: Well I know it's not possible directly by parameters. I'm looking for some alternative "hacky" way, like with Sliders

Answer (score 1):

Ok. After hacking around I've managed to come with solution that is acceptable for me but may introduce some regressions in some situations. pressed and hovered properties are no longer usable

```
import QtQuick.Controls.Private 1.0

ComboBox {
  Component.onCompleted: {
    for (var i = 0; i < combobox_ctrl.children.length; ++i) {
      if (combobox_ctrl.children[i].hasOwnProperty('onWheel') && combobox_ctrl.children[i] !== mouseArea) {
        combobox_ctrl.children[i].destroy()
      }
    }
  }

  MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    anchors.fill: parent

    onPressed: {
      if (combobox_ctrl.activeFocusOnPress)
        forceActiveFocus()
      if (!Settings.hasTouchScreen)
        combobox_ctrl.__popup.toggleShow()
    }

    onClicked: {
      if (Settings.hasTouchScreen)
        combobox_ctrl.__popup.toggleShow()
    }
  }
}
```

This way we can mimic mouse area that was originaly inside the ComboBox. Popup is shown as it was (at least I didn't see any regresion in it yet). However two properties are inaccesible right now

Comment: Thanks a lot! I love this solution as a temporary one until https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48620 gets fixed. I'm going to put it in a separate control so it is reusable

Answer (score 1):

I created a separate file called `NonScrollingComboBox.qml` with the following code following this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33080217/969016

Now I can just use `NonScrollingComboBox` as a component instead of `ComboBox` on places where I don't want the mouse scroll to change the value

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ComboBox {
    id: combobox_ctrl
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (var i = 0; i < combobox_ctrl.children.length; ++i) {
            if (combobox_ctrl.children[i].hasOwnProperty('onWheel')
                    && combobox_ctrl.children[i] !== mouseArea) {
                combobox_ctrl.children[i].destroy()
            }
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressed: {
            if (combobox_ctrl.activeFocusOnPress)
                forceActiveFocus()
            combobox_ctrl.__popup.toggleShow()
        }

        onClicked: {
            combobox_ctrl.__popup.toggleShow()
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
NonScrollingComboBox {
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    model: ["item one", "item 2"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to apply only to [Qt Quick Controls 1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-combobox.html) ComboBox. On [Qt Quick Controls 2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html) ComboBox the wheel mouse event is not enabled by default and can be enabled manually by setting to true the property `wheelEnabled` (documented in the base class [Control](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#wheelEnabled-prop)). Also the combobox won't keep a "focus" on mouse events so you can freely use the wheel on other mouse areas by just entering them.