# Disable mouse wheel for QML Slider

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I want to be able to scroll `Flickable` with mouse wheel (or two fingers on touchpad) **without changing `Slider`s** it may containt.

Sample code and result application:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow

    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 200
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        flickableItem.flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick

        Column {
            Repeater {
                model: 40
                Slider {
                    width: rootWindow.width * 0.9
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: result application]

Looks like there was some [attempt to fix this](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/124669/) in the past, but not successful.

**EDIT**: this relates to `Controls 1.x` only, as controls doesn't seem to have this issue starting from 2.0 version.

Comment: Did you try the fix? (Setting the value of `Slider.wheelarea.enabled` to **false**.)

Comment: @maxik `wheelarea` component of `Slider` isn't accessible from the outside. It should be possible to change it via editing Qt's sources for `Slider`, but I'm afraid that I can't do that either.

Comment: Why do you use the deprecated QtQuick.Controls 1.4 rather than the QtQuick.Controls 2.0?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hack from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33076960/3088216) did it for me.

```
Slider {
    id: slider
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (var i = 0; i < slider.children.length; ++i) {
            if (slider.children[i].hasOwnProperty("onVerticalWheelMoved") && slider.children[i].hasOwnProperty("onHorizontalWheelMoved")) {
                slider.children[i].destroy()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This may not work with other controls (e.g. ComboBox).

Answer (score 5):

You can place `MouseArea`s on the sliders to steal the mouse wheel event.

Something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow

    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 200
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ScrollView {
        id: _scrollview
        anchors.fill: parent
        flickableItem.flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick

        Column {
            Repeater {
                model: 40
                Slider {
                    width: rootWindow.width * 0.9
                    property int scrollValue: 10

                    MouseArea {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onWheel: {
                                //check if mouse is scrolling up or down
                                if (wheel.angleDelta.y<0){
                                    //make sure not to scroll too far
                                    if (!_scrollview.flickableItem.atYEnd)
                                            _scrollview.flickableItem.contentY += scrollValue
                                }
                                else {
                                    //make sure not to scroll too far
                                    if (!_scrollview.flickableItem.atYBeginning)
                                    _scrollview.flickableItem.contentY -= scrollValue
                                }
                            }
                            onPressed: {
                                // forward mouse event
                                mouse.accepted = false
                            }
                            onReleased: {
                                // forward mouse event
                                mouse.accepted = false
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the `onWheel` - event to forward any scrolling to the `ScrollView`. The other mouse events, such as clicking, can be forwarded to the parents (in this case the sliders) by setting `mouse.accepted = false;` for any mouse event you wish to have forwarded.

**Edit:** Oh, I just saw now that you don't want any changes in the sliders contents. You can also to try to place a `MouseArea` all over the `ScrollView` and do the same forwarding.

Comment: thanks! I can place something *over* Slider, but I can not edit Qt's sources for it. Will try it out shortly and let you know about my results.

Comment: Adding further Objects with rather complex event-handlers just to dissable a *feature/bug* of a *deprecated* module, does not seem like a *solution* to me. It seems rather hackish. It would be probably even better, to just reimplement the `Slider` completely. Some might even say, it would be always better to do this, rather than even consider using a QtQuick.Control ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest, if feasible for you, would probably be, to change from `QtQuick.Controls 1.4` which can be either considered [deprecated](http://www.embeddeduse.com/2016/04/10/using-qt-5-6-and-later-under-lgpl/), not maintained, or [low-performing](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/10/qt-quick-controls-2-0-a-new-beginning/) to the new `QtQuick.Controls 2.0`

In this version your issue has been adressed.
To adress your need of `QtQuick.Controls 1.4` we'll import the `QtQuick.Controls 2.0` with an alias:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 as NewCtrl

Column {
    Slider {
        id: oldslider // old slider from QtQuick.Controls 1.4 with your issue
        width: 500
        height: 250
    }

    NewCtrl.Slider {
        id: newsli // new slider without your issue. Both side by side
        width: 500
        height: 30
        wheelEnabled: false // use this to enable or disable the wheel
    }
}
```

Of course you can also alias the old controls and use the new one as the basic... Or alias both. As you like

Comment: you are right, but I need menuBar for my application window which was removed in this version for some reason

Comment: That is bad. No-one should prevent you from using the menuBar. Luckily you can import both: `import QtQuick.Controls 2.0` and `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as OldCtrl` an then use the good old `OldCtrl.MenuBar` ;-)

Comment: Or wait for Qt 5.8 and hope its there.

Comment: after playing with `Controls 2.0` a bit, I realized that it isn't that easy to switch to it when you have medium-large application based on `Controls 1.x` already. Appreciate you answer anyway, thanks!